# R Storm ACK not reaching spout

Tags: r, apache-storm

I'm using the R Storm package written by Allen Day to introduce a R bolt in my topology.
I'm having difficult in acking a tuple within R code. I've reduce my R bolt to do bare minimum work. Ack never reaches Spout. Tuples get retried after hitting timeout interval.

```
executeTuple <- function(s) {
t = s$tuple;

mylist <- as.list(t$input)
s$log(c("ContentID = ", mylist$contentid))

s$ack(t)    
}

storm = Storm$new();
storm$lambda <- executeTuple
storm$run();
```

On the other hand, `s$fail(t)` seems to work. Tuple is retried immediately. Also, I'm able to see the ack by replacing R bolt with Java bolt. Anyone else facing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an bug in ack() function in R-Storm package. This is fixed now.
Do a git pull from repo if you need this.

https://github.com/allenday/R-Storm/blob/master/Storm/R/Storm.R

Any package update after this post should have the fix.